# How to re-install Ubuntu (doesn't matter if the data will be lost)

Tags: system-installation

I messed my Ubuntu up, I can't login to my Ubuntu, I have tried a couple of ways following the instruction on the Internet but it doesn't work. Now I want to reinstall it on my computer. I know that I can just boot my pc using USB and re-install Ubuntu like I had done when I install it, but I'm afraid that there will be 2 Ubuntu version, which may slow down the system (It's already slow). Some instructions from Internet which tell how to protect the data from losing during the re-installation seem to be complicated for me, I don't care if I lose my data. How could I do this?

Comment: You can just boot from the installation media and pick install Ubuntu. Make sure that when it asks where to install ubuntu you place the root there (simply chosing "/") if you have several partitions. The / should go to the partition where you wish to have the new system (in this case where you already have the corrupted operation system). I also reformat the partition picking "ext4".

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

- Boot from Ubuntu installation media and choose <kbd>Try Ubuntu without installing</kbd>
- Open <kbd>GParted</kbd> and format the existing Ubuntu partition with ext4 file system
- Click on <kbd>Install Ubuntu</kbd> - when asked what to do, select <kbd>Something else</kbd>
- Choose the formerly formatted partition to install the root system
- Start the installation process and proceed as you did before

Answer (score 1):

You can just boot the Ubuntu installation device, and choose to erase the entire drive before installing.

By the way, having two systems installed will not make your system slower, but you will have less disk space for each system as the drive is partitioned.